# Google Cloud messaging implementation in Java using MySql

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I’m a java developer on a mac learning to write android code in android studio.  I have been asked to integrate google cloud messaging into an app.

I understand that android studio has a button that puts all the GCM required stuff into the phone / tablet app. However I have no idea about all the changes its making to my app along with a requirement that I not use google as the database. Instead I need to use a local instance of mysql since we have business logic to apply to send out messages to particular users.

I have done all the google server side tasks. I have my app key, project key… etc.

When it comes to examples and tutorials that I’ve tried to find, they are either dated, use different terminology than what google currently uses, use a language other than java for the server side, examples are eclipse based, use a third party library to hide functionality (Kii Cloud) or don’t implement the app/server app using XMMP (CCS).

I’m looking for a straight java server implementation tutorial or example that communicates to google using XMMP and securely to the app on the phone / tablet and classes that someone new to android can follow.

I’ve done the activities on this page http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html and I’ve followed the links under “Next Steps”, however they assume a level of understanding that I don’t have yet. This page and its links give me what configurations and settings I need, but not where to put them and why.

When I’m successful at this, my plan is to condense all the details into a youtube tutorial on how to do this or at the very least a very detailed web page, because I feel that implementing this should not be this hard, especially using Java, Tomcat, MySql and an Android app. This seems like it would be the base case for starting off.

Comment: This is a difficult question for SO's format. Though what you're having difficulty with is relevant, a lot of what you're asking about is offtopic and you're skirting with having your question closed: asking for off-site resources and tutorials is off-topic; talking about having problems getting something to work without providing any details makes it hard to help, and also there's not really a question you're asking here. You'll have better luck if you recast this as a definite question about something specific that someone could answer in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918842/connect-my-exist-server-to-gcm) will help.

Comment: +Eran This illustrates my conundrum perfectly... gcm-server.jar by googles own notice has been depracated. "The information in this document has been superseded by GCM Server and GCM Client. Please use the GoogleCloudMessaging API instead of the GCM client helper library. The GCM server helper library is still valid."  It's not what they want you to use, but you can, and how much longer is it valid?

Comment: @BryanJames No, gcm-server.jar was not deprecated. gcm.jar (the client side library) was deprecated. the GoogleCloudMessaging API replaces only the client helper library. The server helper library can still be used (though it's not necessary to use it, it gives you a quick and simple to use implementation of sending GCM messages).

Comment: +ScottBarta I knew the question was borderline before I typed one character... but I really have no where else to go at this point.  I can't have a specific question because I have so many questions about how to implement this.  Here's but one example. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html  Under the Authentication section it gives a couple of XML config structures for the client and the server.  Great!  I know what I need to put into the code base to make it work... but where do I put it?    It also tells me how to make a request JSON... but it fails to tell me how to send it.

Comment: If you want to find some tutorial about `GCM`, `CCS`, `XMPP` etc, you can refer to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4) and [here](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/).

Comment: [ Here ] ( http://www.javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp ) is everything that you want to do....Hope this will helps you.

Comment: So you do not only ask how to use gcm and get data from a webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Well This question does not have straight forward answer -

Please find below code written in PHP for Server Side-

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of GCM
 *

 */
class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

}

?>
```